# Как отсортировать поля в форме?

Tags: битрикс

Есть форма, компонент `bitrix:infoportal.element.add.form`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваше имя и Ваше сообщение, соответственно Название и Описание для анонса

Email и номер телефона - пользовательские поля.

Можно ли отсортировать поля? Опустить анонс в конец формы?

p.s. Не сделал пользовательское текстовое поле, т.к. автоматом цепляется визуальный редактор.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете кастомизировать шаблон компонента bitrix:infoportal.element.add.form. Но, судя по скриншоту, вы используете его для создания формы обратной связи. Есть какая-то необходимость использовать именно этот компонент? Если у вас bitrix24 то лучше использовать формы из crm, а если только БУС, то стандартные веб-формы - это намного проще и удобнее.

Comment: Изначально и была веб-форма. Под определенную задачу решил переделать в инфоблок